# MPMoviePlayerController is not changing its orientation to Portrait upside down mode

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have started with one view base application and just added MPMoviePlayerController into default view controller that is generated by default by Xcode. see my code below

```
 videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
 videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 250);
 [self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
 [videoPlayer play]
```

I have tried almost everything but not sure what I am missing. See what I have already tried.

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

--> In plist I have provided all orientation.
--> Also added orientation method In view controller on which Player is hosted.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
  return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Note: At first default video will take it's default control style(Embeded) once I will click on full screen button from controls. and I will try to rotate in portrait upside down it is not working.

Comment: only happens in MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen? and what happens, why do you say its not working? it rotates but does not adjunst to new frame?